# Aurelia bundling with relative routes

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have a route setup like so:

`{route: ['faq', 'faq/:query'], name: 'faq', nav: true}`

After bundling, when navigating to the faq page, it requests the resource from the server instead of the bundle.

If I remove the `faq/:query` so that it looks like so:

`{route: 'faq', name: 'faq', nav: true}`

The resources is requested from the bundle as expected.

Is there something I need to add to my `config.js` in order for it to recognize the relative url?

Comment: You need to specify a moduleId with your route configuration. See here for an example: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/src/app.js#L6 Basarat's answer below isn't quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it requests the resource from the server instead of the bundle.

Your server should return the same bundle for all urls supported by the bundle.

## Reason

When a web page user click goes to `/foo` the javascript gets a chance to intercept it. Aurelia does and shows you stuff for `foo`. However when you nav directly to `/foo`, the request goes to the server (after all user might be coming from an emailed link etc) so your server should return the same bundle, then the bundle js (aurelia) loads up, looks that its for `/foo` and then shows the stuff for `/foo`.

MORE : this is common to all SPA frameworks

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because it's actually really good advice. For some reason, it just magically started working, so maybe files weren't getting copied or something, I have no idea. I played around with it for a while and then it just started working.